# In how many different ways can this be done?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Every positive integer is to be coloured according to the following three rules.
(i) Each number is either red or green.
(ii) The sum of any two different red numbers is a red number.
(iii) The sum of any two different green numbers is a green number.
In how many different ways can this be done?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: What happens if $1$ and $m>1$ are the same color?

Comment: only one main solution ? try $1$ in red and all the others in green ( since there is no constraint on the sizes of the sets ). And the reverse colors. If 0 is included, you may have '"only 0,1 red"

Comment: thanks for answer, I tried a lot of ways but ... :)  (answer is 6)

Comment: This is not a whole question, even the question has never given its condition clearly, based on its explanation, we even cannot know accurately why there is a sum for 2 numbers to add.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist the answer is $6$, I suppose it is possible to color every integer the same color? Then the possible colorings are:

- All integers are red
- $1$ is red, all other integers are green
- $1$ is red, $2$ is green, all other integers are red

And these three again, but swapping red and green. The important thing to derive these is that whichever color $1$ is, from the next integer of that color onwards, all integers will be that color.

Answer (score 0):

The possible coloring can be written in the form of $red$$(green)^{k}(red)^{inf}$ and red, green swapped. If k = 0, all are red. If k is 1, it's ok. If k = 2, then 2 + 3 must also be colored green, but it is colored red(1+4=5, where 1 and 4 are colored red). Suppose k >= 2, then 4 + k must be colored green, but k + 4 > k + 1 and we have already chosen it as red. So there are 6 possible colorings. Haha, I forgot one case $red(green)^k$. So that would be plus 2.

Comment: thanks for answer but answer is 6.